# Changing marker style in Matplotlib 2D scatter plot with colorbar according to cluster data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot

I am carrying out clustering and try to plot the result with the scatter plot function of matplotlib.

A dummy data set is :

```
x = [48.959 49.758 49.887 50.593 50.683 ]
y = [122.310 121.29 120.525 120.252 119.509]
z = [136.993 133.128 143.710 129.088 139.860]
```

I am plotting x,y and using z as a color axis using the following code

```
plt.scatter(
x=x, y=y, c=z, label="CO2 Emissions Saved Cumulative", cmap=cm1)
```

[Here is how it looks for the entire data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkQnG.png)

Now, I performed K means clustering on my dataset and found three clusters. For Example

```
[0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]
```

I found the following solution to plot them by differentiating with marker style

```
ax.scatter(x[cluster == 0], y[cluster == 0], marker="*")
ax.scatter(x[cluster == 1], y[cluster == 1], marker="^")
ax.scatter(x[cluster == 2], y[cluster == 2], marker="s")
```

now the problem is, using this method, it overwrites the coloraxis as shown in this example image
[cluster plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJOQ.png)

How can i avoid it to not change the coloraxis of the markers and still use the default z values for the color axis. I want the plot to only change the marker style according to cluster data. and not change the color based on cluster data. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scale each clusters' z-value to the same scale so that you can have a uniform colorbar for the 3 scatter plots. You can use a `Normalize` object to do so and pass this normalization to scatter using `norm=`.

```py
x = np.array([48.959, 49.758, 49.887, 50.593, 50.683 ])
y = np.array([122.310, 121.29, 120.525, 120.252, 119.509])
z = np.array([136.993, 133.128, 143.710, 129.088, 139.860])
cluster = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2])

mini, maxi = np.min(z), np.max(z)
norm = plt.Normalize(mini, maxi)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.scatter(x[cluster == 0], y[cluster == 0], marker="*", c=z[cluster == 0], norm=norm)
a = ax.scatter(x[cluster == 1], y[cluster == 1], marker="^", c=z[cluster == 1], norm=norm)
a = ax.scatter(x[cluster == 2], y[cluster == 2], marker="s", c=z[cluster == 2], norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(a)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Diziet. However, I wish to keep the same scale as shown in the first attached image. The only change I want to add to it is to have a marker style based on cluster. with your suggested solution, it is showing the colorbar range from 0-1 only

Comment: and also, why normalize z values? the clustering was performed on the entire dataset (x,y,z)

Comment: I am achieving the same thing by simply adding c=z[cluster == 0]. The results from this and your solution are similar. This is not what i wanted.

Comment: The goal is to scale each clusters' z-value to the same scale so that you can have a uniform colorbar for the 3 scatter plots. I've included a full code

Comment: awesome, understood. exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A less verbose and more robust solution for large dataset is using the `pandas` and `seaborn` library:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = [48.959, 49.758, 49.887, 50.593, 50.683 ]
y = [122.310, 121.29, 120.525, 120.252, 119.509]
z = [136.993, 133.128, 143.710, 129.088, 139.860]
kmean = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2])

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'z':z, 'km_z':kmean})
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x='x', y='y', hue='km_z', style='km_z')
```

which produces the following output

[image]

Additionally you can use the `pandas.cut` function to plot bins (Its something I regularly need to produce graphs where I can use a third continuous value as a parameter). The way to use it is :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
x = [48.959, 49.758, 49.887, 50.593, 50.683 ]
y = [122.310, 121.29, 120.525, 120.252, 119.509]
z = [136.993, 133.128, 143.710, 129.088, 139.860]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'z':z})
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.z, bins=3)
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x='x', y='y', hue='bins', style='bins')
```

and it produces the following example:

[image]

---

I've used the latter method to produce graphs like the following:

[image]